# SQL query most recent value with conditions

Tags: sql, datetime, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

Another attempt, I wrote a piss poor question the first time. I hope this is better.

I have 2 tables - Patient and clinicalparameterh:

```
PATIENT
ID  Last    First
190 Smith   Frank
191 Smith   Flo


CLINICALPARAMETERH
SBP DBP Datetime            PatientID
124 86  2020-07-13 13:49:05 190
144 86  2020-08-13 13:49:05 190
134 96  2020-08-13 13:49:05 190
120 89  2009-07-13 13:49:05 190
132 76  2009-07-13 13:49:05 190
122 76  2020-07-13 13:49:05 191
```

I need to see

```
ID Last First
```

I would like to see this only if 1) the SBP is <140 and 2) DBP is <90 and 3) these are the most recent readings done in the last year.

So it should NOT make the list if it is from >1 year ago, or is not the most recent reading, or the SBPis >139 or the DBPis >89. (so from this example it would show Flo's name but not Frank, but cause his most recent is out of range)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you. Hopefully I explained what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output based on your sample data? Not just the column heading, but the actual values?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure - this is a query area of an electronic medical record.  Generally as I google around I find some SQL commands that don't work but I've been able to figure out the alternative that works in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use a correlated subquery to get the most recent date.  The rest is filtering.  In standard SQL, you can do this as:

```
select p.*, cph.*
from patient p join
     CLINICALPARAMETERH cph
     on p.id = cph.patientid
where pch.datetime = (select max(cph2.datetime)
                      from CLINICALPARAMETERH cph2
                      where cph2.patientId = cph.patientId
                     ) and
      pch.datetime > current_date - interval '1 year' and
      pch.SBP < 140 and
      pch.DBP < 90;
```

Date/time functions are notoriously dependent on the database, so the exact syntax might vary in the database you are actually using.

Comment: I see duplicates in this - patient listed more than once with more than one date/reading.  not just the most recent date

Comment: The correlation clause should be on "patent" not "date".  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses window functions:

```
select p.*, c.*
from patient p
inner join (
    select c.*,
        row_number() over(partition by patientid order by datetime desc) rn
    from clinicalparameterh c
) c on c.patientid = p.id
where 
    c.rn = 1
    and c.sbp < 140
    and c.dbp < 90
    and c.datetime > current_date - interval '1' year
```

Date functions highly vary across databases, so the last condition may be spelled differently depending on the product you are using: the query uses standard ANSI SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can `rank()` the patients' figures of the last year by the time they were taken in descending order. Then you can filter for only the ones ranked at first position and having the values you're after. Patients where such records exist are the ones you want. So you can use a correlated subquery with `EXISTS` to filter for them.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.last,
       p.first
       FROM patient p
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM (SELECT cp.sbp,
                                         cp.dbp,
                                         cp.patientid,
                                         rank() OVER (PATITION BY cp.patientid
                                                      ORDER BY cp.datetime DESC) r
                                         FROM clinicalparameterh cp
                                         WHERE cp.datetime >= now - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) x
                                                           -- ^ this might vary   ^
                                                           --   depending on your
                                                           --   actual DBMS        
                            WHERE x.patentid = p.id
                                  AND x.sbp < 140
                                  AND x.dbp < 90
                                  AND x.r = 1);
```